# Windows template for changing name of moved file (when same already exists)

Tags: filesystems, windows-registry, templates, naming

I have 2 folders: `from folder` and `to folder`. 
In **each** of these, I have a file named `TEST.txt`.

When I move `TEST.txt` 
from `from folder` to `to folder` 
— surely, this message appears:

[image]

In my case, I want to save *both* files, so I click "Let me decide for each file"; 
then (in a very next window) I pick both "from" and "to" ones, 
and go "OK".

What follows is that Windows automatically takes 
the name of "from" `TEST.txt` (which came from `from folder`) 
and changes it to `TEST (2).txt`.

**The Question** is: what registry key should I create or modify 
in order to customize this naming template?..

I'm familiar with the `CopyNameTemplate`, which rests in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\NamingTemplates`, 
but it only works for cases when you're specifically creating a copy of file right next to original (namely, without changing a folder): *it doesn't affect moving files* as I described.

Therefore, I seek a different naming template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the registry key/value you're looking for:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\NamingTemplates
```

Value name: `RenameNameTemplate`

Comment: Thank you! Too bad it has typical for Windows downsides, but it works.